# Shiny App not responding

Tags: r, shiny

I have written a well functioning Shiny App, and I want to rewrite the code a little bit, to make it more elegant.

My probem: the App is loading for ages, and when it loads, it does not respond anymore. Strange thing that it is functioning well in the old version of the App.

This is what I have right now (after removing nearly everything):

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

function(request){shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
))}
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(crosstalk)
library(tidyverse)

data <- readRDS("report_summary2.rds")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  computeTable <- function(){data %>% select("Year", "Month", "Date", "Transaction")}

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      data = computeTable(),
      filter = "top",
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(
        pageLength = 100
      )
    )
  })
})
```

Unfortunately I cannot share report_summary.rds, as it contains sensitive information, it has like 500.000 rows and 9 columns in total, so dealing with that should not be the issue.

This was working in the old App version like a charm, but now it loads forever, and if I try to use the filters for dataTable (at the top), the App is not responding anymore.

I've been searching and looking, but could not find anything. Possibly anybody sees something?

Comment: (Sounds like it isn't as well-functioning as you claim.) Your use of `computeTable` is a little odd, is there supposed to be some reactivity there? With nothing else, it's going to be rather difficult to troubleshoot. Are there any database or other network connections being made? Is it loading off of a network share? Can you reproduce the latency with another (not-small) base dataset?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to share the exact same data and can create an example dataset, which would help us a lot. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @r2evans. Right now this is the whole App (I deleted the other parts to get to where it slows, and it is coming from the code I shared). The full version of course will have reactivity added, and computeTable is a quite massive function, I minimized it to be sure, that this cannot cause the issue. Right now, in this minimized version, no database connections, no network connections, the file is loading from my computer. I think `DT::datatable` is causing the issue, if I pass `head(data, 100) ` to `data`, it is working ok

Comment: no errors on the console @Ozan147

Answer (score 0):

You are right after > 400 thousand rows DT becomes slow being a single process (as well as Basic Shiny).
Here are some options:

- To store and access data in *RDBMS* or *noSQL*.
- Use [Shiny Pro](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny-server-pro/), which allows to split the load through multiple servers\applications.
- Check as well architecture of your application (too much reactivity will slow it down).

And of course run a [Profiler](http://rstudio.github.io/profvis/examples.html#example-3---profiling-a-shiny-application) to find out where are your real bottle-necks. All other options are
   somehow cosmetic: usage of `global.R`, split data table for
   quick\small and bigger\slow parts etc.